# React. Cannot start function inside the getDerivedStateFromProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot understand, why when I try to start the function `getTodosList` inside the `getDerivedStateFromProps` the method - it always retrun to me the `TypeError - Cannot read property 'getTodosList' of null`.

Also after I start use the `getDerivedStateFromProps` - my function does not start in `componentDidMount` too...

What is I'm doing wrong? (

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            // some state...
    }

    getTodosList = (todos) => {
        console.log(todos);
        const all = [];
        const done = [];

        // some logic...

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { todos } = this.props.state.iteams;
        console.log('componentDidMount', todos);

        this.getTodosList(todos);
    }

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        const { todos } = nextProps.state.iteams;
        console.log(this.getTodosList, prevState.datasets, 'componentWillReceiveProps', todos);

        this.getTodosList(todos); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTodosList' of null

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static property of the class (as indicated by the `static` keyword in front of it). This means it doesn't have access to any instance functions/properties.

Declare your `getTodosList` as static as well (if it also doesn't use any instance properties) then call `Chart.getTodosList(todos)`.

**Edit**:
If you call `setState` in `getTodosList`, you can change it to return the state object instead, then you can construct/update your state based on the returned object from your calling function.

Eg.

```
static getTodosList = todos => {
  ...
  return { someState: someData }; //instead of this.setState({ someState });
}
static getDerivedStateFromProps() {
  ...
  return Chart.getTodosList(todos);
}
```

You also don't need the `componentDidMount` if it's doing the same thing as `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

Comment: if I make `getTodosList` as `static` - I start to get an error `TypeError: _this2.setState is not a function` for this.setState({}) inside it

Comment: That's what I mentioned, static functions cannot have access to `this` instance. Make it return the state object instead of calling `setState` in it, then you can construct/update your state based on the returned object from your calling function.

Answer (score 2):

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is a static method, it will not have the access of any instance property/method, means `this` will not be available inside that method.

Use `componentDidUpdate` to perform the operation you want on state/props change.

You need to put the check between prevState/prevProps vs the new values.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
   // compare this.state and prevState or compare the props values 
   // and perform the operation
}
```

Comment: If I use `componentDidUpdate` for this component, instead of `getDerivedStateFromProps ` - I trap in stackoverflow loop

Comment: that's correct when you will not put the check between the prev values and the new values. use of condition between values then only perform the desired operation, check updated answer.